# How to seperate class into interface and implementation for Java

Tags: java, c++

I come from a C++ background and am trying to learn Java now . For C++ classes , we often split the interface and implementation files into `foo.h` and `foo.cpp` respectively. After which we would link the files using the `#include statement`

For Java , how do i split the interface and implemenation into two separate files similar to what I have done in C++ , what are the steps to be taken ??

Comment: Simply put you don't.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious why dont you do it ???

Comment: Answers from this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092199/is-it-correct-that-header-files-in-c-and-abstract-class-interface-implementati?rq=1

Comment: @Computernerd: It sounds like you actually want this - I have to ask "Why?". In any modern IDE I can't imagine what you hope to gain from this.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there's no such distinction.

The closest thing you can do is to have a strict separation of interfaces and implementation of interfaces (something usually recommended).

so for example you can have a

**IMyInterface.java**

```
public interface IMyInterface {

}
```

and a **MyImplementation.java**

```
public class MyImplementation implements IMyInterface {

}
```

However... this is not the same.... it is more like C++ abstract classes and C++ implementation classes.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `interface` keyword which allows you to declare the public API, which the implementing class can use `implements` to leverage. This is as close as you can get to your desired separation. Java is simply designed differently, there is no such thing as header files. Header files do not serve as interfaces in c++ anyways, they're just the compiler-required units so the compiler knows where to find method signatures.. The more correct equivalent in C++ for the concept of an interface is the abstract base class.

For the answer to why... well, I'll just direct you to this already-answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092199/is-it-correct-that-header-files-in-c-and-abstract-class-interface-implementati)

Answer (score 0):

> ... we often split the interface and implementation files into `foo.h` and `foo.cpp` ...

That's not true, you are confusing the terms *class declaration* and *(abstract) interface*.

Java has no concept of header files, nor does it distinguish class declaration from class definition.